# How compare and count the number of unique values across multiple columns

Tags: r

I am currently looking at something similar to `df` what I would like to be able to do is produce soemthing that looks like `df2`. Where the specified column values are compared next to eachother, the number of specific occurences are counted, and the count is places into a new column in a new dataframe.

For example: in `df` the combination 1, 5, and 9 occur 3 times.

```
df <- data.frame( col1 = c(1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,1),
                  col2 = c(5,6,7,8,5,6,7,8,5),
                  col3 = c(9,10,11,12,9,10,11,13,9))
```

```
df2 <- data.frame( col1 = c(1,2,3,4,4),
                   col2 = c(5,6,7,8,8),
                   col3 = c(9,10,11,12,13),
                   count = c(3,2,2,1,1))
```

I tried using dplyr

```
df2 <- df %>%
  distinct(col1,col2, col3) %>%
  group_by(col3) %>%
  summarize("count" = n())
```

with no success

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  count(col1,col2,col3)

  col1 col2 col3 n
1    1    5    9 3
2    2    6   10 2
3    3    7   11 2
4    4    8   12 1
5    4    8   13 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Is using `plyr` fine?

```
library(plyr)
ddply(df,.(col1,col2,col3),nrow)
```

Output:

```
  col1 col2 col3 V1
1    1    5    9  3
2    2    6   10  2
3    3    7   11  2
4    4    8   12  1
5    4    8   13  1
```

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do it with `dplyr` is using `count()` as suggested by [Vinícius Félix's response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74670125/13015865)

However, here is a fix using the syntax you started. You were thinking in the right direction.

**Library**

```r
library(dplyr)
```

### Solution to your code

```r
df %>%
#  distinct(col1,col2, col3) # you don't need this row, remove it.
  group_by(col1, col2, col3) %>%  # you have to group by all columns you want to check
  summarize(count = n()) %>% # quotes are not needed, but are not wrong
  ungroup()  # Always add ungroup() at the end to solve future problems
```

**Output**

```r
#> # A tibble: 5 × 4
#>    col1  col2  col3 count
#>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <int>
#> 1     1     5     9     3
#> 2     2     6    10     2
#> 3     3     7    11     2
#> 4     4     8    12     1
#> 5     4     8    13     1
```

<sup>Created on 2022-12-03 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>